# Hamel basis for $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{F}_2$

Tags: linear-algebra, hamel-basis

Let $\mathbb{F}_2 = \{0,1\}$ be the field with two elements.

The naturals $\mathbb{N} = \{0,1,2,3,...\}$ (with vector addition given by binary bitwise XOR) form a vector space over $\mathbb{F}_2$, with a Hamel basis $\{2^n \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$. The dyadic rationals $\mathbb{N}[\tfrac{1}{2}]$, with vector addition defined the same way, also form a vector space over $\mathbb{F}_2$ with a Hamel basis $\{2^k \mid n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$.

Viewing $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ similarly as a vector space over $\mathbb{F}_2$, what does a Hamel basis look like? I cannot define its vector addition explicitly as this is an [open problem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/16214/is-there-an-associative-metric-on-the-non-negative-reals). However, this isn't necessary;  my question boils down to finding some $\mathcal{B} \subset \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ such that:

1. Every $r \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ can be identified with a finite subset $X \subset \mathcal{B}$ such that $r = \sum_{x \in X}x,$
2. This representation is unique; $\sum_{x \in X}x = \sum_{y \in Y}y \iff X=Y$.

Comment: I guess you are identifying the numbers with their binary expansions and using exclusive or on those expansions as the vector addition operation - you should have explained this as we shouldn't have to guess such details. You need to be a little bit careful, since binary expansions are not unique. $0.0\dot{1} = 0.1$. Can you edit your question to make it clearer what you are asking.

Comment: As @RobArthan pointed out, you need to define addition in a way that makes $\mathbb R_{\geq0}$ into a vector space. After that, you should probably rephrase the question "what does its Hamel basis look like" since any vector space of dimension $>1$ has more than one Hamel basis (and $\mathbb R_{\geq0}$ would have uncountably many Hamel bases).

Comment: Q: ", what does its Hamel basis look like?" A: Complicated.

Comment: @RobArthan I have edited the question - I hope it's now clearer.

Comment: It is clearer now (although I don't really agree with your claim that it is unnecessary to specify the addition). I am afraid the likely answer is that the only way we have of constructing your basis is via a Zorn's lemma argument that delivers a maximal linearly independent subset. If that turns out to be uncountable, then there will be nothing more we can say about what it looks like unless we have a lot of additional information. I don't know of an example where one has an explicit description of an uncountable Hamel basis. Such examples may exist, but I have no idea where to look for them.

Comment: Can you give one example for the binary operation? Say 5XOR3=.?

Comment: @LawrenceMano 5 XOR 3 = 101 XOR 011 = 110 = 6. If you're familiar with python, this is the `^` operation.

Comment: Thank you. Now it's clear.

Comment: I have come across finite vector spaces and finite dimensional vector spaces and for the first time a vector space with countable vectors. Thank you for the question.